# Make query parameter an endpoint

Tags: permalinks

i want to add custom part at the end of permalink

like this

```
https://example.com/product/product-name/order
```

i want

```
https://example.com/product/product-name?order=1
```

redirect to

```
https://example.com/product/product-name/order
```

thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this code into your product single page before `get_header()` function start.

```
<?php
global $wp;
if( isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && isset($_GET['order']) ){
    $url = home_url( $wp->request . '/order/' );
    wp_safe_redirect( $url );
    exit;
}
?>
```